# Instalar ClosedXML en hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Estoy desarrollando en ASP.NET, C#. Tengo un archivo de excel con un formato preestablecido y estoy usando ClosedXML para abrirlo y llenar la información requerida en las celdas para luego guardarlo y poder abrirlo desde excel.

Funciona perfectamente cuando lo pruebo en modo local, pero al pasarlo al hosting (godaddy) me arroja el siguiente error:

```
"CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClosedXML' could not be found".

Line 8:  using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

¿alguien conoce la manera de instalar ClosedXML en el hosting o qué se necesita hacer o pasar para que reconozca las librerías de ClosedXML?

Comment: Qué tal Antonio, gracias por responder... lo copie a httpdocs, a cgi-bin y a App_Data y sigue el mismo error. No hay un directorio bin, solo el cgi-bin, no sé si haya que agrear un directorio bin dentro de httpdocs.

Answer (score 3):

Mira si lo tienes bien implementado en Referencias del proyecto. Lo encontrarás como paquete Nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/

Tiene que quedarse la referencia dentro del proyecto, ya que lo que seguramente pase es que la dll o la referencia esté excluida de la versión del hosting